# What would be a good place to ask this soft question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently read that the Polish mathematician Stanislas Ulam once challenged one of the great names in twentieth-century economics, Paul Samuelson, to "name me one proposition in all of the social sciences that is both true and non-trivial".$^1$ Samuelson's vote went to the idea of [comparative advantage](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_advantage).

I am interested to know what other professional economists would volunteer as answers. I absolutely can't ask this question on Econ SE since it's opinion-based, neither on the subreddit r/AskEconomics for the same reason.

What are some other communities where this kind of question will be entertained?

$^1$ *The Collected Scientific Papers of Paul A. Samuelson*, vol. 3 (Cambridge, MA: MIT Press, 1966), p. 683

Comment: I don't know how many people will know of a different community. You could try a place like Quora I imagine. That is my best try.

Comment: There is a close cousin of Ulam's question here on Econ SE: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/20992/42